# Taylor Polynomial Proof

Tags: calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

I am going over a previous year's test and I have no idea how to approach this question. If anyone could please help. Let $g(x)=e^{x^2}$.

[image]

Comment: $ $ $ $ what is $g$?

Comment: Sorry about that  g(x) = e^(x^2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Write down the series expansion for $e^t$. Replace $t$ by $x^2$.  Recall the relationship between the coefficients of the Maclaurin series expansion and the $n$-th derivative of the function at $0$.

Comment: I think it would be g^(2n)(0)=(2n)!/n! But I am lost on the piecewise even/odd stuff.

Comment: The powers of $x$ in the series expansion are all even. If we differentiate say $87$ (an odd number) of times, then the lead surviving term has shape $ax$, so derivative at $0$ is $0$. For even $n$, say $n=2m$, the coefficient of $x^n$, that is, of $x^{2m}$, is $\frac{1}{m!}$, and when you differentiate $2m$ times and set $x=0$ you get $\frac{(2m)!}{m!}$. I think you have all these things figured out, but are confused about $n$. It is helpful to split into $2$ cases $n=2m$ and $n=2m+1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a clear explantion.

Comment: If I could please ask another question. For n = 2m+1,  I want to say you get (2m+1)!/(m+1)! I see your logic by taking a few derivatives and how for every odd one you will end up with zero, but how do I put this in general for a proof. Do you have any recommendations  of texts or notes. I am obviously missing something from mine.

Comment: For informal calculus course problems, I would just **assert** that the lead term of the $(2m+1)$-th derivative is $\frac{(2m+1)!}{(m+1)!}x$, or even write down explicitly the general term of the $k$-th derivative. In a course that stresses induction, one can go through a formal proof.